# Command Not Found Jekyll

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I'm trying to create and publish a Jekyll blog using [this template](https://github.com/poole/poole/#readme).

I installed Jekyll initially. Without any luck, I did resort to installing it via sudo. (And have now since uninstalled it!)

Jekyll(1.4.2, 1.0.3) and am running rvm with ruby 2.0.0p195. After installing the gem, I run `jekyll serve` in the folder but get the error: `Zsh Command Not Found`. I tried changing my path to no avail. Any advice on how to troubleshoot?

I cannot uninstall/reinstall nokogiri (see other SO articles on this) because of dependencies related to work projects.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using rvm you should not install gems with sudo. Rvm is user-specific (the binaries are all in your home directory), so putting Ruby stuff in system-wide folders with sudo will not work. Just install without sudo and you should be ok.

The rvm docs tries to explain this a little bit here:
http://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems

> **DO NOT use sudo...**
>
> ...to work with RVM gems. When you do sudo you are running commands as root, another user in another shell and hence all of the setup that RVM has done for you is ignored while the command runs under sudo (such things as GEM_HOME, etc...). So to reiterate, as soon as you 'sudo' you are running as the root system user which will clear out your environment as well as any files it creates are not able to be modified by your user and will result in strange things happening. (You will start to think that someone has a voodoo doll of your application...)

Comment: That's fine and I understand that Casper, the only problem that sudo for me was a last resort! I used 'gem install jekyll' but didn't find success. I know that some people suggested uninstalling and reinstalling nokogiri, however I cannot afford to do that due to dependencies.

Comment: @rdrakey What was the problem when doing `gem install jekyll` without sudo?

Comment: It's installed @Casper, it just won't recognise the command "jekyll". So it doesn't function when I run "jekyll serve".